# Queries run slow after updating database from SQL 2008 r2 to 2014

Tags: performance, sql-server, query

I've changed my database edition from 2008 r2 SQL server express to 2014 enterprise edition. The point is, queries run like 3 times slower than the old server. I'm testing on the same data and I've already tried the following: [SQL Server 2014 upgraded - queries very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995599/sql-server-2014-upgraded-queries-very-slow)

Nothing have changed even after changing the compatibility level. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue by installing an older version of visual studio. I downgraded from 2017 to vs 2015 and it worked like a charm